# "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame" error in Visual Studio but works fine in windbg

Tags: visual-studio, windbg

I am trying to analyze the dump(Process dump) of x64 application. In visual studio 2008 "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame" error is coming, but the PDBs are loaded properly(Confirmed under modules loaded). If the same thing is loaded in WinDbg everything works fine. It gives all the thread's call stack and the line no in the code etc. This happens only with x64 dumps(Dumps are captured from 64 bit task manager and procdump). What could be the problem?

Comment: A little strange but could you check if you have any (probably not) settings under Tools->Debuggin->Symbols. Check if you have any erroneous paths here, you can try clearing this and perhaps manually adding the paths to the symbols

Comment: My VS 2008 was not able to open a 64 bits dump properly, but 32 bits worked.
VS 2010 & 2013 works fine on 64 bits dumps.
I think 64 bits support was an option on 2008, maybe dump file analyse also is an option or not available at all!